# How do I retrieve the datas sent back to a SweetAlert2 Ajax call?

Tags: vue.js, sweetalert2

I'm building a website and using exclusively [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) for my confirmation methods (notification of success, edition or deletion).

Since it takes quite a lot of lines, I decided to set everything related to SweetAlert in a JS file that i would call and use as a function, as follows:

```
// src/config/SweetAlert.js

import swal from 'sweetalert2'
import 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss'
import axios from 'axios'

const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3333/api/v1'
})

const SweetAlert = {
  delete (title, text, type, confirmation, url) {
    swal({
      title: title,
      text: text,
      type: type,
      showCancelButton: true,
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Delete',
      preConfirm: () => {
        return API.delete(url)
          .then(response => {
            return response
          })
      },
      allowOutsideClick: () => !swal.isLoading()
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        swal({
          type: 'success',
          title: confirmation
        })
      }
    })
  },

  // Some other possibilities
}

export default SweetAlert
```

And I use it as follows:

```
// some methods
handleDelete (post, index) {
  const result = SweetAlert.delete(
    `Delete "${post.title}"?`,
    `Are you sure you want to delete "${post.tite}"?`,
    'warning',
    `"${post.title}" was successfully deleted`,
    `/post/${post.id}`
  )
}
```

I would like to make sure everything went well in my API before removing the deleted element from the list. I tried adding `return result.value` since there is the following code block:

```
if (result.value) {
  swal({
    type: 'success',
    title: confirmation
  })
  // Returns undefined as soon as SweetAlert shows up
  return result.value
  // shows up only when I click "Delete" on the Swal modal, has the infos I need
}
```

I tried to change my code to the following:

```
const result = SweetAlert.delete(  // my initial code )

if (result.data === 'ok') {
    this.posts.splice(index, 1) 
}
```

But all I get is "undefined".

Is there a way to retrieve this kind of data?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swal returns a Promise, so make use of it in your `delete` function like that:

```
delete (title, text, type, confirmation, url) {
    let res = swal({
      // your code here ...
    });
    res.then(result => {
      // your code here ...
    })
    return res;
)
```

After that you could use it like this:

```
SweetAlert.delete(  // my initial code )
    .then(result => {
        if (result.value) {
            this.posts.splice(index, 1);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error', error)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, it was easier than I thought, but I didn't thought about this possibility, thanks!